# How let comstants.dart look into another dart file to override true or false

Tags: flutter, icons, hide, appbar

How to let my constants.dart look into my flavors.dart for true/false

I have a Flutter app. When it opens you can provide a 7-digit number. Every numbercode shows different pages in the app. The numbers are based on cities.

On my appbar there is a camera-icon opening a conference site.
I want to be able to hide this camera icon depending on the 7-digit code used.

In my constants.dart I have the following line:  static const bool hideCameraIcon = true;
With true or false, I can show or hide the camera-icon

But I want this to be overridden by code in my flavors.dart.

Here is a part of the code:

```
import 'package:buurtwijzer/constants.dart';

Map<String, Map> flavors = {


  // Beekdaelen
  '0880000': {
    AppConstants.hideCameraIcon: true,

  },
  // Beek
  '0464380': {
    AppConstants.hideCameraIcon: false,

  },
```

How can I let the constants.dart looks into the flavors.dart and override the false or true depending on which 7 digit code is used.

I'm happy to provide dart code if needed.

regards Alan

I tried some code like

```
static bool get hideCameraIconOverride {
    if (code != null && flavors.containsKey(code)) {
      dynamic flavor = flavors[code];
      if (flavor.containsKey('hideCameraIcon')) {
        return flavor['hideCameraIcon'];
      }`
```

But I'm not experienced enough to get it working.